# using cor.test function in R

Tags: r

If `x` be a `n*m` matrix, when I use `cor(x)`, I have a `m*m` correlation matrix between each pair of columns.

How can I use `cor.test` function on the `n*m` matrix to have a `m*m` p-value matrix also?

Answer (score 1):

There may be an existing function, but here's my version. `p_cor_mat` runs `cor.test` on each pair of columns in matrix `x` and records the p-value. These are then put into a square matrix and returned.

```r
# Set seed
set.seed(42)

# Matrix of data
x <- matrix(runif(120), ncol = 4)

# Function for creating p value matrix
p_cor_mat <- function(x){
  # All combinations of columns
  colcom <- t(combn(1:ncol(x), 2))

  # Calculate p values
  p_vals <- apply(colcom, MAR = 1, function(i)cor.test(x[,i[1]], x[,i[2]])$p.value)

  # Create matrix for result
  p_mat <- diag(ncol(x))

  # Fill upper & lower triangles
  p_mat[colcom] <- p_mat[colcom[,2:1]] <- p_vals

  # Return result
  p_mat
}

# Test function
p_cor_mat(x)
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
#> [1,] 1.0000000 0.4495713 0.9071164 0.8462530
#> [2,] 0.4495713 1.0000000 0.5960786 0.7093539
#> [3,] 0.9071164 0.5960786 1.0000000 0.7466226
#> [4,] 0.8462530 0.7093539 0.7466226 1.0000000
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Please also see the `cor.mtest()` function in the **corrplot** package.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/corrplot/versions/0.92/topics/cor.mtest